# Using Date and Time in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to use excel to figure out what time I need to do parts of my experiment. For example: I start process X at 8:00am on 9/25/17 and then need to wait 56 hours, I want excel to out put 4:00pm on 9/27/15.

I have my start time in A2 (formatted as 9/25/2017  8:00:00 AM), hours elapsed in B2, and the formula =A2+TIME(B2,0,0) in C2. It works in the sense that it gives me 4:00PM but does not give me the date.

Comment: Try using `=A2+B2/24`

Comment: 9/25/2017 8:00:00AM

Comment: Then just format C2 to show the date.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=A2+B2/24
```

with the proper formatting:

[image]

Comment: That worked, but now when I want to build on that, it not working. From the date I got from C2, I want to use that to repeat the formula on the next line (A3 is now equal to C2), time elapsed (B3) and C3 =A3+TIME(B3,0,0) but its just giving me whats in A3 as a result